# Vivado "resize" simulation error

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I write code that the sums of the squares of two numbers. If I write code that is shown in code 1 and run simulation according the this, I get like this blue arrow shown in picture 1 (for code 1). I can't simulate this warning or error. However I write code to shown in code 2, I get no error messages and I don't get blue arrow. Difference between the codes only "resize" command. For code 1,

> a_square <= a_in*a_in

a_square signal is 26 bits. I describe as 32 bits this signal. I describe enough bit number for this signal.
Why do I have to use the resize command even though I have defined a sufficient number of bits (32 bit)? Wouldn't it be inconvenient if we define the product of two 13-bit inputs as 26 bits and there is an overflow, 27 bits?
Why does an error go when I type the resize command? What is the reason of this?

Code 1

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
entity square is
      Port ( clk       : in std_logic;
         a_real    : in std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);  --fix_point(13,12) 
         b_im      : in std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);
         out_num   : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end square;
architecture Behavioral of square is
        signal a_in : signed(12 downto 0);
        signal b_in : signed(12 downto 0);
        signal a_square: signed(31 downto 0);
        signal b_square: signed(31 downto 0);
        signal sum : signed(31 downto 0);
        signal sum_vector:std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            a_in <= signed(a_real);
            b_in <= signed(b_im);
            a_square <= a_in*a_in;
            b_square <= b_in*b_in;            
        end if;
    end process;
    sum <= a_square +b_square;
    sum_vector <= std_logic_vector(sum);
    out_num <= sum_vector;
end Behavioral;
```

Code 2

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity square is
        Port ( clk      : in std_logic;
               a_real   : in std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);
               b_im     : in std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);
               out_num  : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
               );
end square;

architecture Behavioral of square is
        signal a_in     : signed(12 downto 0);
        signal b_in     : signed(12 downto 0);
        signal a_square : signed(31 downto 0);
        signal b_square : signed(31 downto 0);
        signal sum      : signed(31 downto 0);
        signal sum_vector:std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            a_in <= signed(a_real);
            b_in <= signed(b_im);
            a_square <= resize(a_in*a_in,32);
            b_square <= resize(b_in*b_in,32);
        end if;
    end process;
    sum <= a_square + b_square;
    sum_vector <= std_logic_vector(sum);
    out_num <= sum_vector;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Because 13*2 is not 32.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you cut down this to a simpler example? That would make it easier for people to see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`a_in` is signed 13 bits wide, so `a_in * a_in` is signed 26 bits wide, with the sign bit at `[25]`. You then assign the result to `a_square`, which is 32 bits wide. There is a size mismatch between the two and the sign bit is in the wrong position (`[25]` rather than `[31]`). The `resize(input, size)` function is sign aware, and correctly handles the conversion from the 26 bit wide `a_in * a_in` to the 32 bit wide `a_square`, placing the sign bit in bit `[31]`.